# is this the correct way to solve the question

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

if there are 6 runners and 3 high jumpers but 2 are also high jumpers and runners,how many people are on the athletic team

my work

6 runner +3 HIGH JUMPERS=9-2=7 members on the athletic team

Comment: Why .... did you multiply?  Would this actually make any sense outside a math class?

Comment: can you help me solve it

Comment: 6 runners and 3 high jumpers is 9 people, but two are counted twice.

Comment: so ur saying theirs 9 people on the athletic  team?

Comment: Why don't you give them names? Alex, Bob, Carol, Dan, Emily and Fred are runners. Emily, Fred and George are jumpers ...

Comment: so since theirs 6 runners + 3 high jumpers ,theirs 9 total members on the athletic team?

Comment: No, there are $9-2=7$.

Comment: oh so there are 7 members on the athletic team,by subtracting 9 which was the high jumpers plus runners subtract the 2 which were also jumpers and runners ,which is the total that their are 7 people on the athletic team

Comment: There are two member of the team that are both runners and jumpers.  Call them Fred and Wilma.  There are six runners.  But Fred and Wilma are runners so they must be included with the runners.  So call the runners:  Fred, Wilma, Bob, Carol, Ted and Alice.  There are three jumpers.  But Fred and Wilma are jumpers so they must be included with the jumpers.  So there is Fred and Wilma and one other.  Call the other Gargamel.  SO we have Fred, Wilma, Bob, Carol, Ted, Alice, and Gargamel.  How many is that?

Comment: that is  7 members on the athletic team

Comment: Why was this question edited to ask about passwords and not athletics, thereby  invalidating the existing answers?

Answer (score 3):

Think about your answer for a moment. The team consists of $6$ runners and $3$ high jumpers, so even if every member of the team competed in just one of the two events, the team would have only $6+3=9$ members. It cannot possibly have $36$ members: that answer simply isn’t even reasonable.

Perhaps it would help to draw a picture. We have $6$ runners, whom I’ll represent by $6$ $R$s, and $3$ high jumpers, whom I’ll represent by $3$ $H$s:

$$R\,R\,R\,R\,R\,R\,H\,H\,H$$

Oops! Two of those high jumpers are also runners; I’ll represent each of them by $(RH)$.

$$R\,R\,R\,R\,(RH)\,(RH)\,H$$

Or you could start with this picture:

```
          R R R R R R H H H
```

and rearrange it like this:

```
          R R R R R R
                  H H H
```

to show that two of the high jumpers are also runners. Either way it should now be clear that the team really has only $7$ members.

But we can arrive at this correct result without resorting to pictures. When we initially compute a total of $6+3=9$ members, we’re counting every athlete who competes in both events twice, once as a runner and once as a high jumper. This means that we’ve overcounted by $2$, and our provisional total of $9$ is too large by $2$; to correct it, we subtract the overcounting and find that the team actually has just $9-2=7$ members.

Multiplying the figures is for a completely different kind of problem. If we had $6$ athletes who specialized in running events, $3$ who specialized in the high jump, and $2$ who did both, and we wanted to form a team of $3$ consisting of one specialized runner, one specialized high jumper, and one athlete who could do both, there would be $6\cdot 3\cdot 2=36$ possible different teams of $3$. This is an application of the product rule for computing the number of ways to make several independent choices. In the your problem here we’re not making choices: we’re just counting the athletes and trying to make sure that we count each one exactly once.

Answer (score 1):

Some people are runners. Some people are jumpers.  Some people are both. Some are neither.

Everyone on the team is one or the other or both.  Noboby on the team is neither.

6 of  the team are runners.  Some of them might or might not be jumpers as well.

3 of the team are jumpers.  Some of the might or might not be runners as well.

2 of the team are both (which means the rest are one or the other and not both).

So how many members are there on the team?

Comment: there are 7 members on the athletic team?

Comment: OK thank you everyone,i got it ,their are 7 members on the athletic team,thank you for correcting me ,i understand where i made my mistake i read the question wrong in the first place.